# импорт нового проекта libgdx в idea

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx, импорт

В пошаговых инструкциях как импортировать новый проект все так просто, но мне ошибку выдает сразу же как только проект открывается 
[image: текст ошибки]
Далее в настройках запуска idea не видит точку входа в классе DesktopLauncher , вообще не воспринимает его как класс, соотв не дает записать его в поле Main.
Что вообще могло поити не так?
[image: Импортирован новый проект]

Comment: А ведь в ошибке вполне достаточно информации. Говорится о том, что кэш `gradle`-а может быть поврежден, поэтому сам градл вам предлагает перезагрузить зависимости и повторить синхронизацию. Т.е. попробуйте клацнуть, `re-download dependencies and...`, градл должен перекачать зависимости и попробовать снова.

Comment: Да, первое что мне пришло в голову - это клацнуть по этим строчкам, но единственное, что происходит - закрывается поле с текстом ошибки и ничего более.

Comment: Если еще актуально - [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025433/how-to-clear-gradle-cache), попробуйте очистить кэш для `gradle` и для самой студии, а потом попробовать заново синхронизировать проект. По идее, градл должен заново скачать все, что нужно, и ошибок быть не должно